storing char in char array - incompatible types in assignment of char to char[]
I have a struct with a char array member as such:
typedef struct {
    // ...
    char myCharArr[200];
} myStruct;

I have a dynamic array of these structs. When I try to store a character in myCharArray it shows an error message of incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char[200]'
int num = 2;
myStruct* data = new myStruct[num];

// ...

data[i].myCharArr = 'a';  // error here

But if I use the line below, it works fine
*data[i].myCharArr = 'a';

I am getting back into C++ after some time so would really appreciate if anyone could explain the difference between the two. From what I understand and remember, I can use strcpy and other variants to store a write a string into a chararray, but it is a single char in this case. Why does dereferencing the array work to store the char into chararray? Additionally, how does the null terminator come into this?

Unrelated: typedef is more like C than C++ here when using with defining classes.

I am getting back into C++ after some time -- I can use strcpy -- I have a dynamic array of these structs -- Why not use std::string?  And a dynamic array in C++ is done by utilizing std::vector.  Your code looks more like C than C++.  If you are just getting back into C++, I recommend you go over the best practices of modern C++ programming.

What is i here. We need a [mcve]

myCharArr is an array. You cannot assign it to a single char. Using operator* dereferences it, and in the case of an array you get a ref to the first character, which you can assign to a char.

data[i].myCharArr gives you the data member myCharArr which is of array type char[200] and you're trying to assing a char to it.

You char array has 200 chars. I wonder which of those 200 you thought data[i].myCharArr = 'a' would change? Thinking about that should answer your question. *data[i].myCharArr = 'a'; is exactly the same as data[i].myCharArr[0] = 'a'; so that answers your second question. *x and x[0]being the same thing is one of the rules of C++, it's just how * and [] work

Final question is that the null terminator isn't in your code at all. But if you want your array to be null terminated, then you have to add the code that will make that so, it isn't done for you. For example data[i].myCharArr[0] = 'a'; data[i].myCharArr[1] = '\0'; makes your array null terminated

assigning a value to an array is just not possible.
You can only copy stuff into the array. for example by iterating over the characters or using other means such as std::memcpy

Be aware you code example is typical for C implementation, but you provided C++ tag only. In C++ his would look a bit different (deeding on context which you didn't provide). Most probably you should use std::string instead char[200].

the application I'm working on is in C++ but it uses the MongoDB C driver due to some issues getting it setup for cpp - hence some C code as well. i can be inferred to be an index to the dynamic array(as im iterating through the array later in the code). Replacing i with 0 should be fine for reproducing

Side note don't do this myStruct* data = new myStruct[num]; in C++, avoid explicit use of new/delete and usw std::vector<myStruct>. If you're coming back to C++ it may be a good idea to read the C++ core guidelines, this will give you a lot of insight on what has changed.

@PepijnKramer thanks for your comment, yes as commented under the accepted answer, there are plans to refactor various bits of the application to use vectors. smart pointers etc


If anyone could explain the difference between the two.

data[i].myCharArr gives us the data member myCharArr which is of array type char[200] and you're trying to assing a character literal 'a' to it which is not possible. Note that c-style arrays also decay to pointer(here char*).

On the other hand, when you apply operator* to *data[i].myCharArr, it is equivalent to writing:
*(data[i].myCharArr)    //same as data[i].myCharArr;

due to operator precedence.
This time, we still get a char[200] from data[i].myCharArr but it decays to a char pointer. The operator* then derefences that pointer and gives us a char which can be assigned 'a'.

Note that in modern c++, you can use std::string, std::array, std::vector etc. Also, you can directly name the class instead of using typedef.

thanks! the operator precedence and decaying to pointer makes it much clearer now. I will eventually be refactoring to use vectors for the struct array, along with smart pointers in other parts as part of improvements to the application but there are certain aspects that will have to be in C due to the mongodb driver.

@SuhaibAhmad I see.  You're welcome :)

@SuhaibAhmad C++ is perfectly capable of using C libraries (or drivers). By itself that is no reason not to use C++ throughout your code. For exmaple if you have a C++ string and you call a function that needs a C string, you just use the c_str or data methods to convert.
